# Al intentar rellenar (UPDATE) tabla con el conector, da error: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000):

Tags: python, python-3.x, mariadb

Tengo dos script de python que parsean datos de un txt y quiero que lo envíen a una tabla `mysql (mariadb V 15.1 )`.

El primer script `"registrosdeentradas.py"` lee las fichadas biométricas de un reloj y carga los datos a la tabla:

```
REATE TABLE `registrobiometrico` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fechahoy` date NOT NULL,
  `legajo` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `horaentrada` time(6) NOT NULL,
  `horasalida` time(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `horastrabajadas` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `saldodia` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `diastrabajadossemana` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `diastrabajadosmes` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `horassemanales` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `horasmensuales` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Con la siguiente consulta:

```
sqlInsertarRegistro = f"""INSERT IGNORE INTO registrobiometrico  (id, fechahoy, legajo, horaentrada) VALUES ({0},"{fhoy}", {empleado.leg},"{entre}")"""
```

Ésta está ok.

El problema se da en el siguiente script: `registrossalidas.py`,
ya que este sólo tiene que ingresar en la misma tabla los datos de salida, probé con:

```
sqlUpdateRegistro = f"""UPDATE IGNORE  INTO registrobiometrico  (horasalida) VALUES ({entre})"""
```

Y al hacerlo me sale:

> `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO registrobiometrico  (horasalida) VALUES (22:30)' at line 1`

Adjunto imagen de la base de datos: [image]

Aquí adjunto mi código:

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
from Empleados import *
import datetime
import time
import re
import mysql.connector

fecha_ahora = datetime.datetime.now()
today = date.today()
x = datetime.date.today()
arrayEmpleados = [nahuel, juan, marco, agustin,gustabo, julian, mariana, judit, agustina, prueba1, prueba2]
HORAS_DE_TRABAJO = 700
diaHoy = x.strftime("%d")
mesHoy = x.strftime("%m")
anoHoy = x.strftime("%Y")
hora = x.strftime("%H:%M")
lector = open("/home/nbaglietto/biometrico/control/salidas.txt", "r")
for linea in lector:
for empleado in arrayEmpleados:

if re.search('^'+str(empleado.leg)+':'+str(diaHoy)+':'+str(mesHoy)+':'+str(anoHoy), linea):
separador = ":"
datos = linea.split(separador)
legajo = datos[0]
dia = datos[1]
mes = datos[2]
ano = datos[3]
horas = datos[4]
minutos = datos[5]
reloj_entrada = datos[7]
hora = int(horas)
minuto = int(minutos)
entre = (horas)+':'+(minutos)
calSalida = horas + minutos
salida = int(calSalida) + int(HORAS_DE_TRABAJO)
exit = str(salida)
andate = (exit[0]+exit[1]+":"+exit[2]+exit[3])
fhoy=(str(anoHoy)+'-'+str(mesHoy)+'-'+str(diaHoy))
print(linea)
print (fhoy)
conexionMySQL = mysql.connector.connect(
host='localhost',
user='root',
passwd='xxxxx',
db='xx')            
sqlUpdateRegistro = f"""UPDATE IGNORE  INTO registrobiometrico  (horasalida) VALUES ({entre})"""
cursor = conexionMySQL.cursor()
cursor.execute(sqlUpdateRegistro)
conexionMySQL.commit()
cursor.close()
conexionMySQL.close()
lector.close()
```

Probé poniendo el ID en la consulta, también sacando `IGNORE`, pero nada resultó. Los script de python son idénticos, pero el error sólo se da cuando quiero realizar un `update`.
Cambié la librería `mysql`: utilicé `pymysql`, `MySQLdb` y decanté por `mysql.connector`.
En Ubuntu tengo instalada `mariadb`  `Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.37-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu`.

Comment: Hola Nahuel, bienvenido, te invito a que hagas el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la sentencia SQL que estás usando para actualizar la tabla. La sentencia SQL correcta sería algo como esto:

```
sqlUpdateRegistro = f"""UPDATE registrobiometrico SET horasalida = '{entre}' WHERE id = {id}"""
```

El problema con tu sentencia es que estás usando `UPDATE IGNORE INTO` en lugar de `UPDATE`. Además, no estás especificando el registro en el que se debe realizar la actualización, por lo que debes agregar una cláusula `WHERE` para especificar en qué registro se debe realizar la actualización.

Debes corregir la sentencia para que se parezca más a la siguiente sentencia:

```
sqlUpdateRegistro = f"""UPDATE registrobiometrico SET horasalida = '{entre}' WHERE id = {id}"""
```

PD: Trata de mejorar tu redacción al realizar una pregunta o consulta. Es muy importante tener una buena ortografía para poder entendernos. Espero y no te vayas del sitio simplemente con la respuesta resuelta, sino también con un enfoque de buena escritura, pues es importante la comunicación y comprensión de parte del emisor hacia el receptor. También trata de añadir tildes invertidas al referirte a bibliotecas o fragmentos de código en medio del texto. Saludos.

Comment: Arego a lo de la ortografía el uso de puntos y comas mas seguido. Cuando no los usas, el mensaje lo leo decorrido y me cuesta mas entenderte.

Comment: Por cierto Ulises, ten cuidado cuando agregas ediciones ortográficas. "Da" es sin tilde ;)

Comment: Según la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) el `IGNORE` es legal.

Comment: Sí, tienes razón @padaleiana Cito: "Según la RAE, la forma «da» del verbo «dar» no lleva tilde."  Lo cierto es que comenté en la edición, "corregí " la mayor cantidad de errores ortográficos, no dije todos, pero tienes razón, apuntado. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por las respuestas, ayer tarde me quede dando vueltas con esto y al final logre hacerlo andar Solo tuve que poner comillas doble  envolviendo los corchete.
la consulta quedo así:

```
sqlUpdateRegistro = f"""UPDATE registrobiometrico SET horasalida = "{sali}" WHERE fechahoy = "{fhoy}" and legajo = {empleado.leg}"""
```

Comment: Eso es bastante inseguro, da la posibilidad de hacer sql injection. Una forma de evitar eso es pasando los valores a la función `execute`

Comment: No lo niego, usar una cadena formateada para construir una consulta SQL es inseguro y puede dar lugar a un ataque de inyección SQL. En su lugar, se recomienda utilizar una consulta parametrizada para proteger su aplicación contra los ataques de inyección SQL.

Comment: Puede usar valores como parámetros separados: `sqlUpdateRegistro = """UPDATE registrobiometrico SET horasalida = ? WHERE id = ?"""
cursor.execute(sqlUpdateRegistro, (entre, id))`